# How can I always show the 'x' to clear a search input in Microsoft Edge?

Tags: css, microsoft-edge

Is it possible to always show the default 'x' in a search input HTML element in Microsoft Edge only by using CSS (without creating custom component)?

[image: image showing an input with the default 'x' for clearing any entered text]

The pseudo-element `::-ms-clear` and the `opacity` property do not have any affect on this 'x' button in Microsoft Edge.

Comment: can u please share a code what you have tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doesn't look like it's possible without creating your own `x` button. From [MDN - `::-ms-clear`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::-ms-clear):

> The clear button is only shown on focused, non-empty text controls. This includes inputs that appear text-like or fall back to type="text".